# Why do I get a different schema when I run generateschema on the command line compared to obtaining it via the api using Django SchemaGenerator?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, schema

I am using the Django Rest Framework SchemaGenerator to create a schema for my API. However, I get different results depending on whether I generate a static schema using

```
python manage.py generateschema
```

compared to when I request a dynamic schema through the API endpoint configured as

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    re_path(r'^auth/', include('api.djoser.urls')),
    re_path(r'^auth/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
    path('schema/', get_schema_view(
        title="Morty",
        description="API to access Morty",
        version="1.0.0"
    ), name='morty-schema'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Using the static method I get a complete schema with all the API endpoints. The schema returned from the endpoint in the dynamic method has a number of endpoints missing.

The set of endpoints given in the dynamic schema is

```
/auth/users/activation/
/auth/users/resend_activation/
/auth/users/reset_password/
/auth/users/reset_username/
/auth/users/reset_username_confirm/
/auth/token/login/
```

which is missing the following endpoints that are present in the full static schema

```
/auth/users/
/auth/users/me/
/auth/users/{id}/
/auth/users/reset_password_confirm/
/auth/users/reset_username_confirm/
/auth/users/set_password/
/auth/users/set_username/
/auth/token/logout/
```

I am using Djoser to get the endpoints and associated views.

I thought, perhaps, that the dynamic schema was affected by authorization, but I tried logging in using the /login/ endpoint prior to requesting the schema and got the same results.

I feel like I must be missing something obvious.